# Return a CompletableFuture containing a list of CompletableFutures

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, completable-future

I'm trying to make the calls to multiple APIs faster.

In the code below, `getFilteredEvents` is the currently synchronous version. I have the feeling that the `map(x -> x.getFilteredEvents(eventResearch))` operation will wait on the response of each API (it uses `RestTemplate.exchange()` internally) before passing onto the next one to build the `List<Event>` that I want to return. A solution would probably be to launch the `map` call on separate threads, but I wanted to try out the `CompletableFuture` API.

Thus, `getFilteredEventsFaster` is the result of my efforts to improve the response time.

```
@Service
public class EventsResearchService {

    @Autowired
    private List<UniformEventsResearchApi> eventsResearchApis;

    // this works, but I'm trying to improve it
    public EventResearchResponse getFilteredEvents(EventResearch eventResearch) {
        List<Event> eventsList = eventsResearchApis
                .stream()
                .map(x -> x.getFilteredEvents(eventResearch))
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return extractResponse(eventResearch, eventsList);
    }

    // this doesn't work yet: what is wrong?
    public CompletableFuture<List<Event>> getFilteredEventsFaster(EventResearch eventResearch) {
        List<CompletableFuture<List<Event>>> futureEventsList = eventsResearchApis
                .parallelStream()
                .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> x.getFilteredEvents(eventResearch)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return CompletableFuture.allOf(futureEventsList.toArray(new CompletableFuture<List<Event>>[0]));
    }
}
```

My understanding is that I would want to send a `CompletableFuture<List<Event>>` back to my frontend, rather than the `List<CompletableFuture<List<Event>>>`, hence the `CompletableFuture.allOf()` call (which, if I understood properly, resembles a `flatmap` operation, creating a `CompletableFuture` from multiple `CompleteableFuture`s).

Unfortunately, as it is, I get a `Generic array creation` compilation error when using `new CompletableFuture<List<Event>>[0]`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have the feeling that using the `join` method would indeed allow me to collect all the answers, but that would be a blocking operation on the thread of my Service, wouldn't it? (Which would defeat the purpose of trying to return a `CompletableFuture` to my frontend, if I understand correctly.)

Comment: Asper the javaDoc of the `allOf` methods states : 
`the results, if any, of the given CompletableFutures are not reflected in the returned CompletableFuture, but may be obtained by inspecting them individually.` And if you look at the type signature, it returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>` so you wont be able to retrieve the list of results of each individual instance of CompletableFuture

Comment: By the way, the equivalent of flatMap for completableFuture is `thenCompose()` which takes a function that takes the element returned by the Future as an input and must returns another CompletableFuture, and instead of using map which would return a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<XXX>>` it only returns a `CompletableFuture<XXX>`. Dont get confused on the `flatMap` of `Stream` returning a 'collection' of item, flatMap is about the Container (in this case CompletableFuture or Stream) not about 'collecting'

Comment: @OlivierL.Applin I'm not sure I understand your comment about flatmap: would it be a blocking operation (requiring the other CompletableFutures to finish before executing the flattening)?

Comment: Yes, thenCompose would require the first Future to finish before executing because the function you passe in to `thenCompose` will be called with the result value of the first Future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following snippet shows the use of `listOfFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join)` to collect the result of `allOF`. I have taken this example from [this page](https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/) that states that it wont wait for every Future to finish.

```java
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        long millisBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> listOfFutures = strings.stream().map(Test::downloadWebPage).collect(toList());
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> futureOfList = CompletableFuture
                .allOf(listOfFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenApply(v ->  listOfFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(toList()));

        System.out.println(futureOfList.get()); // blocks here
        System.out.printf("time taken : %.4fs\n", (System.currentTimeMillis() - millisBefore)/1000d);
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> downloadWebPage(String webPageLink) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () ->{
            try { TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4); }
            catch (Exception io){ throw new RuntimeException(io); }
            finally { return "downloaded : "+ webPageLink; }
            });
    }

}
```

Since efficiency seems to be the issue here, I have included a dummy benchmarck to prove it does not take 32 seconds to execute.

Output :

```
[downloaded : 1, downloaded : 2, downloaded : 3, downloaded : 4, downloaded : 5, downloaded : 6, downloaded : 7, downloaded : 8]
time taken : 8.0630s
```

---

### EDIT from the original Question-Poster

Thanks to this answer, and through using [this website](https://medium.com/@kalpads/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0) (talks about exception handling related to `allOf`), I came up with this completed version:

```
    public CompletableFuture<List<Event>> getFilteredEventsFaster(EventResearch eventResearch) {

        /* Collecting the list of all the async requests that build a List<Event>. */
        List<CompletableFuture<List<Event>>> completableFutures = eventsResearchApis.stream()
                .map(api -> getFilteredEventsAsync(api, eventResearch))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        /* Creating a single Future that contains all the Futures we just created ("flatmap"). */
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures =CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures
                .toArray(new CompletableFuture[eventsResearchApis.size()]));

        /* When all the Futures have completed, we join them to create merged List<Event>. */
        CompletableFuture<List<Event>> allCompletableFutures = allFutures
                .thenApply(future -> completableFutures.stream()
                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                            .flatMap(List::stream) // creating a List<Event> from List<List<Event>>
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );

        return allCompletableFutures;
    }

    private CompletableFuture<List<Event>> getFilteredEventsAsync(UniformEventsResearchApi api,
            EventResearch eventResearch) {
        /* Manage the Exceptions here to ensure the wrapping Future returns the other calls. */
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> api.getFilteredEvents(eventResearch))
                .exceptionally(ex -> {
                    LOGGER.error("Extraction of events from API went wrong: ", ex);
                    return Collections.emptyList(); // gets managed in the wrapping Future
                });
    }
```