# Lost some request from CompletableFuture.allOf

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

The problem is I have to call an API one by one, so I use CompleableFunction as below

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
List<Bclass> listAll = new ArrayList<>();

for (SthClass e : result) {
  CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fundInService.doRetryTransaction(retryTransactionRequestDto), threadConfiguration.getAsyncExecutor())
                            .thenAccept((result) -> {
                                Aclass a = new Aclass();

                                listAll.add(a);
                            });
  completableFutures.add(future);
}

CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
allFutures.get();
```

I got a random size of listAll from allFutures

I don't know what happened to this code, new to Java

Comment: Can you elaborate what you were expecting and what you got ?

Comment: Don’t manipulate a list from actions that may be executed by different threads. Collect a list of result values after the jobs have been completed. Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111717/2711488).

Comment: it is because you do.not wait when listAll is completed

Comment: @janardhansharma I expect to get `listAll` contains 10 lists but I randomly get it.

Comment: @Holger seems right but let me try, thanks for sharing this

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov what do you mean?

Comment: add the line where you get the size of listAll

Answer (score 0):

Use `synchronizedList` instead of `ArrayList`,because `ArrayList` not thread-safe

```
List<Bclass> listAll = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList() );
```