# Asynchronously run all elements in a list (unknown size) of CompletableFutures

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to run a list of asynchronous code blocks. I found some help in [older threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108125/return-a-completablefuture-containing-a-list-of-completablefutures), but the results are inconsistent and show me that not all asynchronous results are completing as expected.

In this sample code, I prepare a `List<CompletableFuture<List<Integer>>>`. The list contains a bunch of futures that I want to collect all at once, without waiting one at a time. Each async block just copies the current list of Integers into a new list.

```
        List<CompletableFuture<List<Integer>>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
            ints.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
            if (ints.size() < 5) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("Input ints: %s", ints));
            CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> future =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    () -> {
                        return new ArrayList<>(ints);
                    });
            futureList.add(future);
            ints.clear();
        }
```

The output is as expected

```
Input ints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Input ints: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Input ints: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
Input ints: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
Input ints: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
Input ints: [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Input ints: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
Input ints: [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
Input ints: [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
Input ints: [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
```

Next, I want to collect the results of each future. The code is

```
        try {
            CompletableFuture<List<List<Integer>>> allInts = CompletableFuture
                .allOf(futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenApply(v ->
                    futureList.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
            System.out.println(String.format("Output ints: %s", allInts.get()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

The output is inconsistent. Sometimes none of the int lists show up, sometimes some of them show up. Sample results:

```
Output ints: [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44], [45, 46, 47, 48, 49], []]
------------
Output ints: [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [20, 21, 22], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44], [45, 46, 47, 48, 49], []]
------------
Output ints: [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

It's clear that not all of the futures are completing, even though I am running `.thenApply()` on the `.allOf()` result. I suspect something is incorrect with the `.allOf()` input, but I am not sure. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you're using the physically the same list in all futures, so depending on time when future is executed - it will see different state of array, you need to create separate copy, for example like this:

```
final List<Integer> finalInts = ints.stream().toList();
System.out.println(String.format("Input ints: %s", finalInts));
CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> future =
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> {
                    return finalInts;
                });
```